# How do I create and push new files client side?

Tags: google-apps-script-editor, google-apps-script-api, clasp

Simply making files in the directory does not add them to the project. Is there a way to make sure they get pushed with the rest of the project, or am I doomed to creating them in the web editor and then pulling?

Comment: You can create spreadsheets  in apps script.  Look at [SpreadsheetApp Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) or the [DriveApp Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app) in the documentation.  Spreadsheets aren't really part of a project. The [project](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/projects) just contains gs and html files.  If the script is bound to a Spreadsheet then you can open it with SpreadsheetApp.getActive() but when you save a project you're not saving any spreadsheets.

Comment: According to the docs (https://github.com/google/clasp#push) they should get pushed just fine, provided they are the correct type. You don't mention the kinds of files you're creating, or what the output of `clasp status` is, so we can't do anything but suggest you help us help you.

Comment: tehhowch; Creating new JS scripts. There isn't a visible file listing I can add them to, and simply having new files in the folder doesn't seem to work. For example I want to make a "test" file that contains functions that test other functions, as it stands now I have to open the project server side, create a new blank script and then pull it again.

Comment: Cooper, I want to make more script (gs/js) files not spreadsheets.

Comment: @J.G. I'd say you're actually experiencing this bug: https://github.com/google/clasp/issues/507 https://issuetracker.google.com/123311608

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any .js or .html files in the directory not excluded by the `.claspignore` file will be pushed to the associated Apps Script project. **You can view these files with `clasp status`.**

[Official Description](https://github.com/google/clasp#push):

> Push
>   Force writes all local files to script.google.com.
>
> Ignores files:
>
> - That start with a `.`
> - That don't have an accepted file extension
> - That are ignored (filename matches a glob pattern in the `.claspignore` file)

e.g.

```
$ clasp create
 ...
$ echo 'function foo() { console.log("This is a Stackdriver log"); }' > newFile.js
$ clasp status
Not ignored files:
└─ appsscript.json
└─ newFile.js

Ignored files:
└─ .clasp.json
$ clasp push
└─ appsscript.json
└─ newFile.js
Pushed 2 files.
$ clasp open
Opening script: https://script.google.com/d/..../edit
```

In the Script Editor, you will observe the files that were pushed by `clasp push`. If you perform an immediate `clasp pull`, you will not observe differences in the files (well, perhaps other than LF/CRLF conversions).

- you may currently encounter [this display issue](https://github.com/google/clasp/issues/507): https://issuetracker.google.com/123311608

if so, the solution is to push a second time before opening the editor.

```
$ clasp push && clasp push
  ...
$ clasp open
```